# skip XML element with xmllint

Tags: xml, shell, xmllint

I have following XML :

```
<root>
  <Type1 name="">
    <Type2 name="">
      <Type3 name="">
        <finalType name="">
          <element value=""/>
        </finalType>
      </Type3>
    </Type2>
  </Type1>
</root>
```

I would like to reach the value of element in the `<finalType>`, usually I write :

```
echo //root/Type1/Type2/Type3/finalType /element@  xmllint etc...
```

BUT in my application the finalType can be in Type1 or Type2 !  ,so I'm looking for something like that

```
echo //root/***/finalType /element@  xmllint etc...
```

but unfortunately it doesnt work .. 
 Do you have any idea How to "skip"  the Type1 , Type2 ... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the double slash (or `descendant::`):

```
echo ls /root//element            | xmllint --shell file.xml
echo ls /root/descendant::element | xmllint --shell file.xml
```